# time series analyses: evaluation of non-independent measurements

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am completely lost with time series modelling.

I have two time series; one contains annual temperatures, the other only summer temperatures. My aim is to test whether there is a significant temperature increase over the years or not. My first attempt was to simply try a linear model. However, I was told that I had to take into account the non-independence of the measurements, as the temperature of a year might be related to the temperature(s) of the year(s) before. I found no option to alter an `lm` - model to the needs of a time series, so I wondered which other options I have. In `lme` in the `nlme` - package, I could for example specify a correlation term (which could help me with my issue, but is no help as I have no random groups, I suppose).

These are the annual temperatures:

```
> annual.temperatures
   year temperature
1  1996    5.501111
2  1997    6.834444
3  1998    6.464444
4  1999    6.514444
5  2000    7.077778
6  2001    6.475556
7  2002    7.134444
8  2003    7.194444
9  2004    6.350000
10 2005    5.871111
11 2006    7.107778
12 2007    6.872222
13 2008    6.547778
14 2009    6.772222
15 2010    5.646667
16 2011    7.548889
17 2012    6.747778
18 2013    6.326667
19 2014    7.821111
20 2015    7.640000
21 2016    6.993333
```

and these are the summer temperatures:

```
> summer.temperatures
   year temperature
1  1996    10.99241
2  1997    11.83630
3  1998    11.99259
4  1999    12.41907
5  2000    12.06093
6  2001    12.27000
7  2002    11.79556
8  2003    13.32352
9  2004    12.10741
10 2005    11.98704
11 2006    12.89407
12 2007    11.24778
13 2008    11.85759
14 2009    12.51148
15 2010    11.29870
16 2011    12.35389
17 2012    12.33648
18 2013    12.24463
19 2014    12.31481
20 2015    12.73481
21 2016    12.43167
```

Now I found a lot about ARIMA and related models, but for a newbe like me, this is all very difficult to understand. `Arima`, for example, gives me the following result. However, I do not know what/how to specify within `arima`. I also do not really understand what the result tells me.

```
> arima (annual.temperatures$temperature)

Call:
arima(x = annual.temperatures$temperature)

Coefficients:
      intercept
         6.7353
s.e.     0.1293

sigma^2 estimated as 0.3513:  log likelihood = -18.81,  aic = 41.63
```

These are many questions. To keep it practical, my question is: how can I adequatly answer the question whether there was a significant warming from 1996 to 2016 regarding the annual as well as the summer temperatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simple solution was to use the `gls` command:

```
library(nlme)

my_model <- gls (temp ~ time, 
            data = my_data, 
            correlation = corAR1 (form = ~ time))
summary (my_model)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to use the `lme4` package assuming you have continuous data that is more or less normal in its distribution.

I also recommend you read the walk-through shown [here](https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter17.html) to make sure you understand the nomenclature for model specification.

Finally, using the `tab_model` command in the `sjplot` package makes formatting your output very efficient.

Comment: Thanks! The link is fixed!

Comment: In `lme4`, I would use the `lmer` function. However, I do not use any random effects here, so `lmer` doesn't work. Or did I get that wrong: do I need to specify some kind of artificial random effect?

Comment: If you want to model the independence of the observations, you need something like `lmer` and it requires at least one random effect.  You probably should read the materials here for more details:  http://gseacademic.harvard.edu/alda/

Comment: I might be wrong, but I do not think that I want to model the independence of observations. I just do want to know: "did temperatures rise significantly?". If I understood right, I have to use a model that takes into account the non-independence of the measurements.